# Write18: capturing shell (script) output as command/variable?

Tags: shell-escape, scripts, output

Let's say I compile the following file with `pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

File listing is:

\immediate\write18{ls /usr}

\end{document}
```

This will send the output of the command `ls /usr` to report/log of `pdflatex` (primarily to `stdout`).

There are then two cases I'd like to utilize:

- The output of `ls /usr` being included directly in the document (LaTeX stream).
- The output of `ls /usr` becoming the contents of a `\newcommand` (by this I mean, that I'd like the script to be executed when the `\newcommand` is executed first - and upon subsequent calls to the new command, the shell code should not be executed anew).

I have read through [How to execute shell script from LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252957/how-to-execute-shell-script-from-latex), but I'm not sure if this "pipe input" can be applied to `\newcommand`.

I have also read through [tex - How can I save shell output to a variable in LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671079/how-can-i-save-shell-output-to-a-variable-in-latex) - and it seems that Tex' file I/O should be used; but I'm quite disliking the fact that I'd still have to redirect the script output (actually, in this case, the `ls /usr` output) to a file, and then read it in, to have it as contents of a command.

So, is there an easier way to achieve what I'd want (hopefully, illustrated through an example based on the above code)?

EDIT: Ehm, I should have asked one more question earlier :) I'll try with an edit here, although it will probably get missed .. :)

I originally asked for a `\newcommand` that will execute shell code only upon its definition (i.e., in a sense it is "cached"); and the answer from @egreg does exactly that. But then - would it be possible to have a different `\newcommand` definition, such that each time this newcommand is called, the shell command is executed anew? I.e. executing something like `\@@input|"cat tempfile"` (which cannot be executed as such), where `tempfile` changes between calls?

Comment: You can say `\newcommand{\foo}{\@@input|"cat tempfile"}` (protect it with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`; each call of `\foo` will run the shell command.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup\makeatletter\endlinechar=\m@ne\everyeof{\noexpand}
\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\TeXpath{\@@input|"which tex" }}\x

\begin{document}
File listing is

{\catcode`_=12 \ttfamily
\input{|"ls /usr" }

}

\TeX{} is \TeXpath
\end{document}
```

We must use `\@@input` (the primitive `\input` command) because `\input` in LaTeX does assignments. The setting of `\endlinechar` is to avoid a spurious space in the expansion of `\TeXpath`.

When shell escape is active and the primitive `\input` finds a `|`, it accepts as input the standard output of the following shell command.

There should be a package by H. Oberdiek that does something of this kind.

***Note*** An assignment is any TeX operation that gives a meaning or a value to a control sequence or register. During the `\edef` operation, TeX expands all commands it finds between the braces until only unexpandable tokens remain, but *doesn't perform any assignment*; rather, something like `\catch=22` (where `\catch` is the name of a count register) remains completely inaltered. Since the definition of `\input` in LaTeX is

```
\@ifnextchar\bgroup\@iinput\@@input
```

the implicit assignments performed by `\@ifnextchar` would not be performed and *both* `\@input` and `\@@input` would be expanded, which results in a complete disaster. Conversely, the `\input` primitive (that LaTeX saves as `\@@input`) is expandable and its expansion consists in causing TeX to read the named file. One has, of course, to be careful about what this file contains, as also this will be expanded. So other precautions have to be taken when doing this kind of operations, depending on the nature of the tokens produced by the command we want to perform and this "solution" is only a skeleton for possible "real" applications.

---

## Update 2019

After some years, things have changed and better methods are available.

For instance, with `xparse` and `expl3` the code can be improved:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\captureshell}{som}
 {
  \sdaau_captureshell:Ne \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl { #3 }
  \IfBooleanT { #1 }
   {% we may need to stringify the result
    \tl_set:Nx \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl
     { \tl_to_str:N \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl }
   }
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_set_eq:NN #2 \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sdaau_captureshell:Nn
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { #2 } { } #1
  \tl_trim_spaces:N #1 % remove leading and trailing spaces
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sdaau_captureshell:Nn { Ne }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\captureshell*[\TeXpath]{which tex} % we need to stringify it because of _

File listing is

{\ttfamily\captureshell{ls \jobname.*}\par}

\TeX{} is \texttt{\TeXpath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

We could add an error message if the user doesn't pass the `-shell-escape` option for the LaTeX run.

Check also `texosquery` (requires Java).

Comment: @egreg: can we do it without a temporary file?

Comment: @xport: this does *not* use a temporary file.

Comment: @egreg: How to use your code above, I got an error when compiling it. I am using Windows.

Comment: @xport Did you enable the shell-escape on the command line with `--enable-write18`?

Comment: @egreg: Yes. Of course. I think "which tex" is the source of problem.

Comment: @xport: use any command that the Windows shell accepts. That was only by way of example.

Comment: Hi egreg, could you explain "We must use `\@@input` (the primitive `\input` command) because `\input` in LaTeX does assignments." a bit further? I'm not sure what you mean by assignments.

Comment: @egreg *When shell escape is active and the primitive `\input` finds a `|`, it accepts as input the standard output of the following shell command.* I'm late to the party, but is there a way to make `\input` accept as inputs both stdout and stderr of the command?

Comment: @Jubobs Try redirecting STDERR to STDOUT.

Comment: @egreg Oh, do you mean in the shell command itself?

Comment: @Jubobs `\input|"ls WHATEVER* 2>&1"` gives me `ls: WHATEVER*: No such file or directory`; without `2>&1` the error message is in the log file

Comment: @egreg Yes, that works. Thank you. Do you know whether STDERR can be captured directly, though, without messing with the command itself?

Comment: @Jubobs No, there's only an input channel; you can redirect STDERR to a file and then examine it.

Comment: @egreg Ok. I'm trying to avoid saving anything to external files. I'll redirect STDERR in the shell command, so. Thanks again!

Comment: This fails for me with `Undefined control sequence.\sdaau_captureshell:Nn ...->\tl_set_from_file:Nnn
                                                  #1{}{|"#2"}
l.26 \captureshell[\TeXpath]{which tex}`

Comment: @Karalga Are you sure you have an up-to-date TeX distribution?

Comment: I thought I had, but turns out I did not.

Comment: I am trying to do `\captureshell[\version]{git log -1 --pretty=format:"\@percentcharh\@percentcharx3b\@percentcharad" --date=short}`, but it seems like `.tex` is being appended to the command (the error is `unknown date format short.tex` - this is on Windows, now latest MiKTeX.

Comment: @Karalga Sorry, but I cannot test MiKTeX. Recall that for using `\@percentchar` you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`; you seem to be missing spaces, though.

Comment: I should have searched harder. appending ` .` helps, and `\captureshell[\version]{git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h%x3b%ad" --date=short .}` now works.

Comment: I'm attempting to use the 2019 solution (with `\sys_shell_get` replaced with `\sys_get_shell`). This works fine as long as the shell command doesn't need to be expanded first (i.e. I've got some `\edef`ed variables in there). Is there a simple way to expand the command fist? All my attempts so far have failed miserably. E.g. how to get this to work: `\captureshell[\someVar]{cat \someOthervar}`?

Comment: @Darhuuk I fixed the typo and added full expansion of the argument.

Comment: @egreg Fantastic, thank you so much! I don't have my head wrapped around the expl3-syntax yet. Seems so easy in hindsight :).

Comment: In the second solution tl;dr the key point is to use the `\sys_get_shell:nnN` expl3 function. Side note, `\cctab_select:N \c_other_cctab` in the setup to be foolproof -- at least excluding the case of XeLaTeX character char code ≥ 256 and weird catcode.

Comment: I really like the updated solution. I kind of would have liked it as a separate answer. However, it not only solves my issue of capturing (calling git log too often is extremely slow otherwise) but also the stringification to work with underscores. Many thanks.

Comment: I've tried to define `\captureshell*[\NTeX]{ls *.tex | wc -l}` and then added in the text `Number of \TeX{} in current folder is: \num{\NTeX{}}`, using the `\num` from `siunitx` package. But it gives me error.

Comment: @LEo No error for me. Did you run `pdflatex` with `-shell-escape` enabled?

Comment: @egreg yes. The error message is: `! Argument of \__siunitx_number_parse_loop_main_digit:NNNN has an extra }.`

Comment: @LEo What's the console output if you add `\show\NTeX`?

Comment: @egreg `> \NTeX=macro: ->1.` the right number of .tex files in current folder

Comment: @LEo Now I see! You have `{}` that’s the cause of the problem. Use it after a macro when you want to preserve a space, which is out of the question here.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a simple way of doing this, using my `bashful` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{bashful}

\begin{document}
\bash[script,stdout]
ls -F /usr
\END
\end{document}
```

which generates
[image: Incorporating the output of <code>ls</code> into your LaTeX document]

Comment: This doesn't seem to save the output to a variable, which I probably the main point of the question?

Comment: The output is stored in `\bashStdout`, and without the `script` option, the output is not expanded by the `\bash` command itself.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this snippet will be helpful in this thread.

https://gist.github.com/w495/7328b76e76aee49657e0bd7a3b46c870

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\ProvidesPackage{bashline}[2016/10/24 v. 0.1]

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\bashline@file@name}[1]{%
        /tmp/${USER}-${HOSTNAME}-\jobname-#1.tex%
    }
    \newread\bashline@file
    \newcommand{\bashline@command@one}[2][tmp]{%
        \immediate\write18{#2 > \bashline@file@name{#1}}
        \openin\bashline@file=\bashline@file@name{#1}
        % The group localizes the change to \endlinechar
        \bgroup
            \endlinechar=-1
            \read\bashline@file to \localline
            % Since everything in the group is local, 
            % we have to explicitly make the assignment global
            \global\let\bashline@result\localline
        \egroup
        \closein\bashline@file
        % Clean up after ourselves
        \immediate\write18{rm \bashline@file@name{#1}}
        \bashline@result
    }
    \newcommand{\bashline@command@many}[2][tmp]{%
        \immediate\write18{#2 > \bashline@file@name{#1}}
        \openin\bashline@file=\bashline@file@name{#1}
        % The group localizes the change to \endlinechar
        \newcount\linecnt
        \bgroup
            \endlinechar=-1
            \loop\unless\ifeof\bashline@file 
                \read\bashline@file to \localline%
                \localline
                \newline
            \repeat
        \egroup
        \closein\bashline@file
        % Clean up after ourselves
        \immediate\write18{rm \bashline@file@name{#1}}
    }
    \newcommand{\bashline}[2][tmp]{%
        \bashline@command@one[#1]{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\bashlines}[2][tmp]{%
        \bashline@command@many[#1]{#2}%
    }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\urandomstring}[1]{%
    \bashline{cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc "A-Za-z0-9" | fold -c#1 | head -1}%
}

\newcommand{\bashdate}{%
    \bashline{date --iso-8601}%
}

\newcommand{\bashdatetime}{%
    \bashline{date --iso-8601=seconds}%
}

\newcommand{\commit}{%
    \bashline{git describe --dirty }%
}

\newcommand{\commitlog}{%
    \bashline{git log -1 --oneline}%
}

\newcommand{\branch}{%
    \bashline{git describe --all}%
}

\endinput
```

It is based on [Antal's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70858/113926)  in «How can I save shell output to a variable in LaTeX?». For example check `\urandomstring`. It generates new random string with every call. Also, see `\bashlines` macros.
It works for me like native `bash`.

Here an example:
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/580e8926fe7b0dfd2ef8ae52

As you can see, `\bashdatetime` gives a different nanoseconds each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my package [`iexec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/iexec):

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{iexec}
\begin{document}
File listing is:
\iexec{ls /usr}
\end{document}
```