# How to use underscores with pgfplotstable?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have an input file like this:

```
some_entry 123
another_entry 456
yet_another_entry 789
```

and I want to typeset it as a table with:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space]{FILENAME}
```

Problem is that LaTeX seems to interpret the underscores as a command to typeset subscript.

Escaping the underscores in the input file does not work.

Comment: `\begingroup\makeatletter\@makeother\_\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space]{FILENAME}\endgroup` might work

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution for the problem which works without category codes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  header=false,
  columns/0/.style={
    string type,
    postproc cell content/.code={%
        \pgfplotsutilstrreplace{_}{\_}{##1}%
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfplotsretval
    },
  },
  ]{
some_entry 123
another_entry 456
yet_another_entry 789
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

the solution is based on the following observations:

1. you do not really have column names, right? I added `header=false` which causes `pgfplotstable` to assign column indices as names (starting with 0).
2. Your first column is of string type and not a number, so I added that as style.
3. This is, of course, the key part: LaTeX (not pgfplotstable) interpretes _ as math mode subscript token. So: we have the choice to render the entire text in math mode (not what we want) or we replace the subscript token by a suitable text token. That's what I did: I added a postprocessor which applies string search-and-replace: it replaces `_` by `\_`.

The approach works for both inline tables and input files.

---

Note that the story would be slightly different if you had column names containing underscores - in this case, you would need to add `column name` such that the column name is typeset correctly and our example would become:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/A_d/.style={
    string type,
    column name=$A_d$,
    postproc cell content/.code={%
        \pgfplotsutilstrreplace{_}{\_}{##1}%
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfplotsretval
    },
  },
  ]{
  A_d B
some_entry 123
another_entry 456
yet_another_entry 789
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works because math mode `_` are actually expandable, so they can be part of column names.

Answer (score 4):

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,columns/colname1/.style={string type}]{FILENAME}
```

And the file should look like that:

```
colname1 colname2
some\_entry 123
another\_entry 456
yet_another\_entry 789
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer - I was motivated by [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51192/how-to-use-underscores-with-pgfplotstable#comment106076_51192)'s comment to try to hack further, but I failed, and these are my notes; maybe they'll help eventually finding a hack/workaround.

The thing is, I have a `.csv` file that would otherwise pass in other software - and it would have passed in pgfplotstable too, if it wasn't for the damn underscores; so now I'd have to escape that file, and have copies of the same data in two files, which I dislike extremely.

So basically I tried to write a small regex script in Perl that would automatically escape nasty characters; and then with `-shell-escape`, capture the `\write18` output, to be used as input for `\pgfplotstableread`; unfortunately, it seems that as long as we use a token/macro in its argument, the `\pgfplotstableread` will decide it's a *filename*, not inline content - and it will of course, fail finding such a file:

> `!` Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '" etmp "'. In case you intended to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed up your end-of-lines? [...]

or

> `!` Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'var name,var length,value, [...]

The few times when I did manage to get stuff interpreted as data (cannot remember how, though), the process would fail with:

```
\pgfplotstable@result ...futilensuremath {4}\\GDM_
                                                  LANG&\pgfutilensuremath {8...
```

I cannot tell exactly, but it looks like in this case, `pgfplotstable` actually tries to make command tokens out of the data (probably via `\csname` .. `\endcsname`) - and because of this, I guess no changing of catcodes would ever help (as can be seen by the example below).

Btw, the only thing I did manage to do once, but I couldn't reproduce twice, was to get Latex to somehow enter mathmode while typesetting the table, in which case it didn't choke on the underscores anymore, and could compile - but, it interpreted them, and typeset them, as subscripts. Interestingly enough, that occured while I was trying to *disable* math codes for underscore (note that I don't really know if math codes can be disabled; never found an explicit reference about that - just tried to change them wildly, and see if I can get a similar effect; I cannot).

Here I'd just like to note [How can LaTeX code in a data file be read by pgfplotstable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52424/how-can-latex-code-in-a-data-file-be-read-by-pgfplotstable/52633#52633) :

> pgfplotstable assumes that column names do not contain expandable material.
>   Its way of dealing with "display names" is to provide the display names explicitly using the column name key which is used during \pgfplotstabletypeset.
>   Protecting expandable material in column names is unsupported. It is unlikely that pgfplotstable will support such protection automatically in the future (because protection cannot be done during \edef which is a common use case of access to columns).
>   So, the answer is: no, this is generally unsupported. Period.

So here is the, currently uncompilable, example code (with comments) that I used so far - maybe it helps eventually finding a hack for this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{tikz} %graphicx
% \usepackage{xcolor} % \pagecolor
% \pagecolor{yellow!15}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{trace}

\def\csvfile{test.csv}
\begin{filecontents*}{\csvfile}
%# this is my .csv table example; data generated with:
%# $ env | grep 'G\(NO\|DM\)' | column -t -s'=' | awk '// {printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1,length($1),$2,length($2));}' | sed 's/_/-/g'
var name,var length,value,value length
GNOME-KEYRING-CONTROL,21,/tmp/keyring-JcALFh,19
GDM-KEYBOARD-LAYOUT,19,us,2
GNOME-KEYRING-PID,17,1989,4
GDM_LANG,8,en-DK,5
GDMSESSION,10,gnome-2d,8
GNOME-DESKTOP-SESSION-ID,24,this-is-deprecated,18
\end{filecontents*}

% don't include # here, we need it as comment char? it needs to be, for \x
% don't escape dollar, though? cannot, also it alone is mathmode..
% also escaped \\?
% actually, the easiest is to add noexpand everywhere, instead of just a backslash??
\begin{filecontents*}{escdat.sh}
perl -ne '$_ =~ s/([@#%{}])/\\noexpand$1/g;
$_ =~ s/(\n)/^^J$1/g;
$_ =~ s/(_)/\\noexpand\\$1/g;
print $_' "$1"
\end{filecontents*}

% \let\)\relax % in the end, \{ causes ! TeX capacity exceeded,
% the problem is all these escapes end in commands!
% escape all in a group @#_\$%{} :
% echo -e " # $ % { _ } \n # # % % $ $ # @ " | perl -ne '$_ =~ s/([@#_\$%{}])/\\$1/g; print $_'
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16794/2595
\begingroup\makeatletter\endlinechar=\m@ne\everyeof{\noexpand}
\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\getEscaped{\@@input|"bash escdat.sh \csvfile" }}\x
% \global\let\textunderscore\relax
% \typeout{\getEscaped}

\gdef\smallcheck{ %
  \typeout{BSL '\BSL' \the\catcode\expandafter`\BSL, %
    DLR '\DLR' \the\catcode\expandafter`\DLR, %
    NHS '\NHS' \the\catcode\expandafter`\NHS, %
  }
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185740/2595
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69294/2595

\begingroup
  \catcode `\|=0
  |catcode `|\=11
  |catcode `|$=11
  |catcode `|#=11
  |catcode `|_=11
  |gdef|LF{\n} % \LF becomes (ASCII) "\n" (verbatim char!)
  |gdef|n{\n} % \n becomes (ASCII) "\n" (verbatim char!)
  |gdef|ELF{\\n} % \ELF becomes (ASCII) "\\n" - escaped backslash for shell!
  |gdef|BSL{\} %
  |gdef|DLR{$} %
  |gdef|NHS{#} %
  |gdef|USC{_} %
%   |xdef|etmp{|getEscaped}
  |smallcheck % new catcodes here: BSL '\' 11, DLR '$' 11, NHS '#' 11,
|endgroup

% back to old catcodes here: BSL '\' 0, DLR '$' 3, NHS '#' 6,
\smallcheck

\gdef\textunderscore{}
\edef\etmp{\getEscaped}
\typeout{\etmp}

\traceon
% \begingroup
\global\let\mytable\relax
\edef\tmpcmd{\noexpand\pgfplotstableread[%
  col sep=comma,
  % hash/number sign # should be comment char by default.
  % # is: ASCII 35=0x23 hex
  %comment chars={\^^23},
  %ignore chars={,\^^24}, % 0x5c=92='\', 0x24=36='$' % bad, ! Improper alphabetic constant. for \uC macro:->\uC ,\$ - backslash?
  %comment chars={\#}, % can do without this
  ignore chars={\noexpand\\,\noexpand\$,\noexpand\{}, % \BSL, \DLR are: ! Improper alphabetic ...
  string replace*={\noexpand\USC}{...}, %nowork % {\_}{+},% nowork
  header=true,
% ]{./test.csv}\mytable
]{ ^^J
\# trying a hack \noexpand\\^^J
\etmp
}\noexpand\mytable %
} \tmpcmd
% ! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '" etmp "'. In case you intended to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed up your end-of-lines? Try `row sep=crcr' and terminate your lines with `\\' (refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details).
% means it is read with \string - no chance to expand a macro inside there
% \endgroup
% with the \edef and traceon:
% \GenericError  ...
%                                                   \endgroup
% <to be read again>
%                    \#
% \pgfplotstableread@filename ->"
%  \#
%                                      trying a hack \\
%  var name,var length,v...
% \pgfplotstableread@openfile ...tableread@filename
%                                                   .tex \ifeof \r@pgfplots@re...
% \pgfplotstableread@impl@ ...otstableread@openfile
%                                                   \def \pgfplotstableread@im...
% l.95 } \tmpcmd


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begingroup
  \catcode`_=12
  \gdef\myunds{_}
  \typeout{catcode 1: \the\catcode`_} %catcode 1: 11
\endgroup %

\typeout{catcode 2: \the\catcode`_} % catcode 2: 8
% \typeout{catcode 3: \the\catcode`\myunds} % ! Improper alphabetic constant.
\typeout{catcode 3: \the\catcode\expandafter`\myunds} % catcode 3: 8

\typeout{myunds \myunds}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62705/underscore-in-textmode-vs-mathmode

\node[] at (current bounding box.south) {
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begingroup%
% \traceon%
\makeatletter\@makeother\_%
\catcode`\_=11 %
\catcode`_=12
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_
\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
\mathcode`\_="202B %\mathcode`_="8000
\gdef\_{W}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
  every row/.style={before row={\catcode`_=11\mathcode`\_="202B\def_{+}\relax}},
  font=\tiny,
  %   every row/.style={before row={}},
  string replace*={_}{\myunds},%
  columns/value/.style={string type},% ,column type={l}
  columns/var name/.style={string type},% ,column type={l}
]\mytable
\endgroup
% \makeatother%
}%
};

% for \pgfplotstabletypeset[]\etmp:
% ! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'var name,var length,value,
% value length
% GNOME-KEYRING-CONTROL,21,/tmp/keyring-JcALFh,19
% so it thinks its a a filename, which it isn't

\end{tikzpicture}

% trace gives:
% \pgfplotstable@result ...futilensuremath {4}\\GDM_
%                                                   LANG&\pgfutilensuremath {8...

\end{document}
```