# Underscore in textmode vs mathmode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, subscripts, catcodes, text-mode

I use `_` character often in text mode, so I changed category of underscore: `\catcode\_=12`, but that applies also to mathmode and now I'm unable to make subscripts with underscore in mathmode. Is there a way to make latex interpret underscore in text mode as the underscore character, and in mathmode as subscript?

Comment: Check the `underscore` package.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can make `_` math active:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \catcode`_=12
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
  \mathcode`_="8000
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \catcode`_=12
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
  \mathcode`_="8000
}

\begin{document}
a_b $a_b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What are the advantages of this code over my more simplistic solution (below)?

Comment: This code is in general more robust: in `\write` operations the underscore will be written as is. Active characters may do surprising things, at times; math active characters, on the contrary, assume the "active aspect" only when typesetting math, so well down TeX's digestive process.

Comment: @egreg: I think you have a spurious `\def\mathunderscore` in your first code snippet.

Comment: @JLDiaz: I don't know where to paste your answer. This solution worked after pasting after usepackage but before begindocument

Comment: If you do this, be aware of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245880/.

Answer (score 11):

```
\catcode`\_=\active
\def_{\relax\ifmmode\sb \else \_\fi}
```

Comment: Where do I put this? Just after `\catcode\_=12` ?

Comment: Better to do it _instead_ of making it catcode 12.

Answer (score 10):

FWIW, in ConTeXt the special characters `_` and `^` do not need to be escaped in text mode and work correctly in math mode.

ConTeXt table and math alignment macros do not use `&` as an alignment marker, so `&` also does not need to be escaped in text mode.

Answer (score 2):

The underscore `_` is *already* math active by default: one does not need to explicitely set its mathcode to `"8000`. Thus one could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_%
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}_%
  \catcode`_=12
}

\begin{document}
a_b 

$a_b$
\end{document}
```

It is perhaps better to do as in [JLDiaz's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62706/4686) and rather than make it catcode `12`, make it catcode `13`, and change its active definition to do as `\_` hence `\textunderscore` only in text mode.

However this will cause problems in labels; except if the activation is done via Babel services, as babel patches various things to allow use of shorthands in labels.

But it was dangerous with Babel `3.8` (I don't know about `3.9`) to have a shorthand also mathematically active, as the `\normal@char<char>` was defined to be the catcode `12` version (if it is already catcode `12` at the time of declaration to babel as a shorthand), but in math mode, with a math active character this creates an infinite loop.

Thus, the `\catcode` ``_ 12` thing avoids these potential difficulties.