# Errors in LyX after outreg2 command (Stata)

Tags: tables, errors, lyx

Unfortunately, I know very little about TeX-coding and so don't know what's wrong with the code below. It is produced by the `outreg2` command in Stata (which so far has always worked fine) and imported (through `\input{...}` ) into LyX.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
\begin{tabular}{lcc} \hline
 &  & (1) \\
EQUATION & VARIABLES &  \\ \hline
 &  &  \\
votes & highest_prom & 0.615** \\
 &  & (0.28) \\
 & middle_prom & 0.410* \\
 &  & (0.22) \\
 & Constant & 0.121 \\
 &  & (0.20) \\
 &  &  \\
 & Observations & 135 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{*** p<0.01, ** p<0.05, * p<0.1} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using `_` as part of a regular name. That character denotes a subscript will follow, but requires math-mode. You could quickly fix this by using `middle\_prom`.

You could also add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
```

to your LaTeX preamble and use `\detokenize{middle_prom}` in the table (the T1 font encoding provides a text-based underscore. For alternatives, consider reading [Underscore in textmode vs mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62705/5764).