# How to ignore underscores inside mathmode

Tags: math-mode

I want to make the expression inside this a text

```
\frac{   fa_das_tat_C    }{1+0.2 }
```

that will not be changed in any way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide working examples, not just lines of code . `\_` should yield underscores, but it does not look nice ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Underscore in textmode vs mathmode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62705/underscore-in-textmode-vs-mathmode)

Comment: exactly i've tried \_ but it doesnt look too nice so i would prefer another solution.  Furthermore do u know any way to online convert latex to swf besides codecogs.com (which doesnt work ;( )

Comment: Please clarify your intentions: is it by any chance `\[ \frac{\textit{some\_identifier}}{n+1} \]` (say) what you are looking for?  (It doesn’t look good in text style, however.)

Comment: @jknappen Tis might be a duplicate, but not of the one you gave for closing reason.

Comment: You could use \verb$fas_das_tat_C$, especially if it is a name and not a product of many variables.

Comment: downvoted without  comment?

Comment: Does anyone else think the question title is confusing?  All the comments and answers suggest that the OP wants to keep the underscores, not ignore them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you want is to transform the numerator into a text style (no italic and no subscript). This should do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{fa\_das\_tat\_C}}{1+0.2 }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```