# Timing response of externally called commands via write18: blocking or not?

Tags: shell-escape

I was wondering: when we use `\immediate\write18{...}` to run commands in an external shell from Latex, is the `\write18` a blocking call or not? In other words, will it wait for the external code to complete and return (with success, or not) - or will Latex just initiate execution in a separate thread in a non-blocking manner, and continue immediately afterwards?

Can an example be supplied that illustrates this?

Comment: As far as I know, `(La)TeX` has absolutely no support for multi-thread or multi-core setups. Anyway, in this specific case, how would you expect the asynchronous protocol to behave? The external command is supposed to have an impact on what `TeX` does on the rest of the document...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @T.Verron - I didn't really have much of an expectation either way; I just couldn't track down an explicit mention quickly, forcing me to write a test case - so I thought it would be better to post it `:)` Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/web2c/web2c.pdf) for Web2c explains the shell escape feature for TeX engines based on Web2c, e.g. TeX Live. Section "4.5 Shell escapes":

> The *shell-command* string is passed to the command shell (via the C
>   library function `system`). The output of *shell-command* is not
>   diverted anywhere, so it will not appear in the log file, or anywhere
>   but the terminal output. The exit status of the system call is also
>   not available to TeX.

The `system` function is explained in its [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html):

> `system()` returns after the command has been completed.

Thus `system` is a "blocking call". That allows that the command creates a file that can be read after the `\write` in LaTeX, for example. Otherwise it would not be possible, because there is no interface for checking the status of the child (no `wait`, ...); it could happen that LaTeX finishes `\end{document}`, before the command execution is finished.

In short:

- `system` is a "blocking call"
- Be aware of the difference `\immediate\write18` and `\write18` without `immediate`. The latter execution is deferred to the next page shipout.
- Keep in mind security. There are options to control, whether commands can be executed. The new restricted mode (enabled by default) has further restrictions.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @HeikoOberdiek - wasn't aware this was already in the docs; great to have this as reference. Cheers!

Comment: I used a write18 shell script to write to an external file, and then downstream in the tex file I `\input` that external file I have just written.  But the result is that the `\input` got the contents of the external file BEFORE the script's execution.  This seems to suggest non-blocking behavior.  Any clue why this happens?

Comment: @YanKingYin There are too many unknown variables as the operating system, the TeX port, the script, ...

Comment: Yes, seems that my TexMaker cannot make system calls.  Not a problem with \write18.

Comment: @YanKingYin Option `-shell-escape` enables `\write18`. Restricted shell escape is often enabled by default, but this cannot be used for arbitrary scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a self-answer, as I didn't find this info anywhere explicitly - `\immediate\write18` seems to have a blocking behavior.

I used `perl` on Linux, with a `for` loop with a `sleep` inside as the test program; it turns out, it's a bit itchy to escape the linefeed `\n` as raw ASCII for the external shell command - so, one needs to be careful about that. Otherwise, the MWE below produces the following output, when Latex is called with `-shell-escape`:

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(./test.aux)
Check: outputting command: 
 echo 'for($ix=0;$ix<5;$ix++){ print("perl $ix \n");sleep 1;};' ; perl -e 'for(
$ix=0;$ix<5;$ix++){ print("perl $ix \n");sleep 1;};' 

 \LaTeX typeout: Before write18 

for($ix=0;$ix<5;$ix++){ print("perl $ix 
");sleep 1;};
perl 0 
perl 1 
perl 2 
perl 3 
perl 4 

 \LaTeX typeout: After write18 

(./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Clearly, the `\write18` waited for the `perl` code to execute first - before allowing Latex to continue onwards.

Here is the MWE, `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69294/2595
% must escape backslash like this, to have escaped linefeed  
% character \n in \write18 output for the shell (raw ASCII)!
\begingroup
  \catcode `~=11
  \gdef\mytilde{~}
  \catcode `\|=0
  \catcode `\\=11
  |gdef|LF{\n} % \LF becomes (ASCII) "\n" (verbatim char!)
  |gdef|n{\n} % \n becomes (ASCII) "\n" (verbatim char!)
  |gdef|ELF{\\n} % \ELF becomes (ASCII) "\\n" - escaped backslash for shell!
|endgroup

\edef\cmd{%
  %echo 'for($ix=0;$ix<5;$ix++){ print("perl $ix \LF");sleep 1;};'
  % below works, with a previous definition of linefeed (with
  % non-escaped backslash) \n as macro; then linefeed char is verbatim
  %echo 'for($ix=0;$ix<5;$ix++){ print("perl $ix \n");sleep 1;};'
  % like this for escaped-backslash-linefeed to propagate through shell;
  % the programs see escaped backslash then:
  %echo 'for($ix=0;$ix<5;$ix++){ print("perl $ix \ELF");sleep 1;};' ;
  %
  % The proper one is with \n/\LF; don't forget `;` separators for bash
  % (as latex will compact these in a single line anyway)
  %
  echo 'for($ix=0;$ix<5;$ix++){ print("perl $ix \n");sleep 1;};' ;
  perl -e 'for($ix=0;$ix<5;$ix++){ print("perl $ix \n");sleep 1;};'
}

\typeout{%
  Check: outputting command: ^^J
  \cmd% OK
}

\typeout{^^J \LaTeX typeout: Before write18 ^^J}

\immediate\write18{%
  \cmd% OK
}%

\typeout{^^J \LaTeX typeout: After write18 ^^J}

\end{document}
```