# Crashes when using \tikzsetnextfilename?

Tags: auxiliary-files, tikz-external

I just stumbled on this, so I'll post about it in Q&A format:

I decided to try tikz-external, and all I have is this in preamble:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=img/] %activate
```

... and the initial tests I ran were fine. But, I didn't like the `test-figure0` default names given by the package; and I wanted to use something like this for the images:

```
\tikzsetnextfilename{\jobname-mypic}
```

However, as soon as I put this in; latex would start generating the file, and then would crash at the end? It even seemed to me - as if that second latex run, ends prematurely -- however, [Timing response of externally called commands via write18: blocking or not?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185739/timing-response-of-externally-called-commands-via-write18-blocking-or-not) confirms that the shell escape call should be blocking (and so it should wait until the spawned "externalization" call to latex completes, succesful or not).

So I debugged a bit, by changing some stuff in the shell command (increasing verbosity by removing `batchmode`, and adding some sleeps):

```
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
% -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"} % default; batchmode=quiet!
-jobname "\image" "\texsource" ; echo "After pdflatex!" ; sleep 2 ; echo "After sleep!"},
external/optimize=false, % because of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170291/tikz-wont-let-me-externalize-and-halts-on-error/172017#172017
}
```

... eventually this produces a log like this:

```
...
(./img/mypic.tikz
% ... runs here...
% (then this - from img/test-mypic.log):
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, image externalization failed: the resulting image
was EMPTY. I tried to externalize 'img/test-mypic', but it seems there is no such image in the document!?
l.526 \end{document}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on img/test-mypic.log.
After pdflatex!
After sleep!
% (then this from test.log):
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call ... did NOT result in a usable output file ...
...
```

... meaning it is spefically the "inner" externalization call to pdflatex that fails - but there are no apparent errors in that file at all? (and the same one externalizes well without a custom name).

So what could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\jobname` command always contain the current compilation steps job-name. Hence your code will recurse down and change `\jobname` which is not what you want.

The `external` library has provided the command:

```
\tikzexternalrealjob
```

which does exactly what you want (the main TeX files jobname).
So what you want is:

```
\tikzsetnextfilename{\tikzexternalrealjob-mypic}
```

and it should work just fine.

Comment: Goddammit, I wish this information popped out of the manual at me, instead of me wasting a couple of hours debugging and such `:/` Many thanks for the answer, @zeroth - cheers!

Comment: No worries... :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, indeed, this:

```
\tikzsetnextfilename{\jobname-mypic}
```

... or rather, the use of `\jobname` there... By putting this:

```
  \edef\tmsg{IZCK tikzexternal@getnextfilename: pgf@tempa '\pgf@tempa', }%
  \typeout{\tmsg} %
```

in the end of `\def\tikzexternal@getnextfilename` in `texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzexternalshared.code.tex`; I could see this in the logs:

```
$ grep -r IZCK .
...
./test.log:IZCK tikzexternal@getnextfilename: pgf@tempa 'img/test-mypic',
./img/test-mypic.log:IZCK tikzexternal@getnextfilename: pgf@tempa 'img/img/test-mypic-mypic',
```

Clearly, the problem is that in the second, externalization call, the `\jobname` is modified by the externalize library, and so that change recurses into `\tikzsetnextfilename`.

So, I thought maybe I could use the main file name instead of the `\jobname` - that turns out not to be straightforward: [Macro to retrieve the real name of the source file if pdflatex is invoked with -jobname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31746/macro-to-retrieve-the-real-name-of-the-source-file-if-pdflatex-is-invoked-with/54894#54894)

Finally, I settled on creating an auxiliary file `mjob.id`, where upon first run I'd store the main `\jobname` as `\mjobname`. The subsequent, recursive calls would then read this `\mjobname` name from the file; and apply it to the `\tikzsetnextfilename`:

```
\IfFileExists{mjob.id}{%true-branch
}{%false-branch
  % NB: \immediate goes everywhere!
  \newwrite\mjobfile
  \immediate\openout\mjobfile=mjob.id
  \immediate\write\mjobfile{\noexpand\gdef\noexpand\mjobname{\jobname}}
  \immediate\closeout\mjobfile
}
\input{mjob.id}

...

\tikzsetnextfilename{\mjobname-mypic} %
```

And finally, this seems to stop the recursion of names, and the crash at the end of the externalizing call - and creates all files as requested.

Comment: Well in this case the command `\tikzexternalrealjob` exists, is this what you are looking for? So `\tikzsetnextfilename{\tikzexternalrealjob-mypic}`

Comment: Thanks for that, @zeroth - had no idea that command exists; somehow I didn't catch on to it while reading the manual. Cheers!