# Percentage character in header of pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am trying to create a table with data from a `.xslx` file exported to `.csv` with `pgfplotstable` but I have trouble with the percentage sign. One of the columns in the header includes the percentage character and I keep getting the error

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
```

but this error only occurs when I try to name a header column with the percentage character (which is what I want!)

I am trying to get something like

```
--------------------
 Data   2%  Compare   
--------------------
 Data1  1      2
 Data2  3      4
--------------------
```

MWE that works: (Notice placement of `\%`)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test01.csv}
Data,  2,    Compare
Data1, 1\%,  2
Data2, 3,    4
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]{test01.csv}
\end{document}
```

MWE that does **not** work:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test001.csv}
Data,  2\%, Compare
Data1, 1,   2
Data2, 3,   4
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]{test001.csv}
\end{document}
```

[As suggested by @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51192/how-to-use-underscores-with-pgfplotstable#comment106076_51192) I have tried `\begingroup\makeatletter\@makeother\%` before `\pgfplotstabletypeset` but this does not work for the percentage character.

Comment: Are you free to adjust the data file?  The problem is that `2\%` is being used as a column name.

Comment: Do you have to put the percent character there? You can add it later using `column/<column name>/column name=2\%` where column name being whatever you wish `2p`,`2` etc.

Comment: I can fortunately edit the header of the data file. So I give the troublesome column header a dump name (2p) and rename it hereafter with `columns/2p/.style={column name={2\%}`? This seems to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it later using `column/<column name>/column name=2\%` where column name being whatever you wish `2p,2` etc.