# pgfplotstable with .tsv file where the headers have underscores: How to avoid "Missing $ inserted"?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, booktabs

The file I want to show is a .tsv file that I cannot edit. It looks like this:

```
up_gene up_chr  up_strand   up_Genome_pos
APLP2   chr11   +   129991686
BACE2   chr21   +   42617990
BRDT    chr1    +   92470856
CTBS    chr1    -   85028940
DHRS1   chr14   -   24761405
```

But when reading this I get a `Missing $ inserted` error. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% recommended:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every even row/.style={
    before row={
      \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}
    }
  },
  every head row/.style={
    before row=\toprule,
    after row=\midrule
  },
  every last row/.style={
    after row=\bottomrule
  },
  string type,
  columns={up_gene,up_chr},
]
{results.tsv}

\end{document}
```

Which results in the error mentioned above, and this output:

[image]

So I have two questions:

1. How can I avoid the error I get? Note that the same error arise even if I remove `columns={up_gene,up_chr}`
2. How can I get the underscore in the header to show? I don't want to subscript the g in `up_gene`.

Comment: have you tried http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51192/how-to-use-underscores-with-pgfplotstable

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, I did try to do something with `columns/A_d/.style`, with `A_d` exchanged for my header name, but I was not able to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the column names yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% recommended:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  columns={up_gene,up_chr},
  columns/up_gene/.style={column name=up\_gene},
  columns/up_chr/.style={column name=up\_chr},
  every even row/.style={
    before row={
      \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}
    }
  },
  every head row/.style={
    before row=\toprule,
    after row=\midrule
  },
  every last row/.style={
    after row=\bottomrule
  },
]{results.tsv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to cope with underscores in a different way, but it requires changing the category code of `_`, which might have adverse effects if math formulas are involved; also loading `fontenc` with the `T1` option is necessary.

Here the two typesettings are shown side by syde: right as above, left with the columns selected by their indices and the change in the category code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% recommended:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  columns={up_gene,up_chr},
  columns/up_gene/.style={column name=up\_gene},
  columns/up_chr/.style={column name=up\_chr},
  every even row/.style={
    before row={
      \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}
    }
  },
  every head row/.style={
    before row=\toprule,
    after row=\midrule
  },
  every last row/.style={
    after row=\bottomrule
  },
]{results.tsv}
%
\begingroup\catcode`_=12
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  columns={[index]0,[index]1},
  every even row/.style={
    before row={
      \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}
    }
  },
  every head row/.style={
    before row=\toprule,
    after row=\midrule
  },
  every last row/.style={
    after row=\bottomrule
  },
]{results.tsv}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a clue what I could do if I didn't know beforehand what the column names were?

Comment: @L42 That I don't know. In my opinion there should be a function for “postprocessing” the found column name, say for applying `\textbf` or similar; in this case one could apply `\detokenize` or do a more sophisticated approach with string substitutions.

Comment: Is there any way to do this automatically. Eg if I don't know exactly know the column names but I just want to replace _ by \\_ in each column name?

Comment: @Peutch Your hope is fulfilled.