# How to get the current directory name in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

Assume the file, `source.tex` is placed in `/home/user/Birds/` and the user types `context source.tex` to compile the file. Is there a way for ConTeXt to retrieve the name of the folder that the file is located in (in this example, "Birds"), for use as a variable? This might be used, for example, to give the document a title, e.g. `\title{\directoryname}`.

- This will only be used on a Linux system and needn't be compatible with other systems.
- Directory names with spaces might appear, e.g. `/home/user/Tropical\ Fish/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\starttext
  \cldcontext {lfs.currentdir ()}
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\SetMacroToShellOutput` defined below will set the given `csname` to the ouptut of the shell command that is provided to it.  So

```
\SetMacroToShellOutput{\DirectoryNameWithPath}{pwd}
```

will set `\DirectoryNameWithPath` to the full Unix path of the current file name.
You can use any Unix comamnds other than `pwd` and get the desired result.  For instance

```
    \SetMacroToShellOutput{\FileNameWithoutPath}{basename `pwd`}
```

will set `\FileNameWithoutPath` to the current file name (without the path).

### References:

- The macro `\SetMacroToShellOutput` is based on [Specify file name shell access via \@@input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102365/specify-file-name-shell-access-via-input).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\SetMacroToShellOutput[2]{% 
  \begingroup\endlinechar=\m@ne\everyeof{\noexpand}%
  \edef\TempResult{\endgroup
    \expandafter\def\noexpand#1{%
      \@@input|"#2" }}%
  \TempResult}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\SetMacroToShellOutput{\DirectoryNameWithPath}{pwd}%
DirectoryNameWithPath = \DirectoryNameWithPath
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or like in Context, Latex users can just use Luatex: ``\directlua {tex.sprint (lfs.currentdir())}``.

Answer (score 2):

In ConTeXt:

```
\starttext

\ctxlua{context(os.resultof("pwd"))}

\stoptext
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is specific to the LuaTeX engine?

Comment: The question is tagged "context-mkiv," so yes, this is luatex.

Comment: Ah; I'm not terribly familiar with either ConTeXt or LuaTeX, but I understood ConTeXt to be *just* a format—didn't know MkIV was LuaTeX-specific :)

Comment: @Sean Allred: If you’re curious about Context’s Lua integration, I can recommend [mk.pdf](http://pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/mk.pdf), [hybrid.pdf](http://standalone.contextgarden.net/current/doc/context/pragma/general/manuals/hybrid.pdf) and the lists [status-files.pdf](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/088de88944c1f2254250bb448c7371a87ff7ee39:/tex/context/base/status-files.pdf) as well as [status-lua.pdf](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/088de88944c1f2254250bb448c7371a87ff7ee39:/tex/context/base/status-lua.pdf).