# How can I get pgf's foreach to iterate over the contents of an input file

Tags: input, foreach

I would like to write something like:

```
\foreach \myline in {\input{filehandle}}
{\dosomethingwith\myline}
```

If I have an `outside_file.tex`:

```
this,
is,
the content, of, a
file
```

and then try to pass it to a `\foreach` loop as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\dosomethingwith[1]{\textbf{#1}\par}

\begin{document}

Output as expected:\par
\foreach \myitem in {this,is,the content, of, a file}
{\dosomethingwith\myitem}

Output not as expected:\par
\foreach \myitem in {\input{outside_file}}
{\dosomethingwith\myitem}

\end{document}
```

I do not get the result I expect.

Here's an image of the result:

[image]

I once saw some package for loading and storing the content of a file in a macro.  But I can no longer find that package.  If you know the package I am referring to, I would accept since that will solve the problem I'm having here.

Comment: finally found the package I'm looking for `catchfile`.  But, I would nevertheless be interested in someone explaining why I can't just directly use `\input{...}` as I have above.

Comment: Is that similar to [textmerg](http://ctan.org/pkg/textmerg)?

Comment: @cfr I don't know `textmerg`.  Is that new?  I haven't updated my LaTeX installation since about July.

Comment: Anyway, \foreach is not really set up for this.  What you need is plain TeX \loop, \repeat, \ifeof, \openin, \closein and \read.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you need to load the whole contents of the file and use it as a parameter of the `\foreach` macro. Then you can replace the line

```
\foreach \myitem in {\input{outside_file}}
```

in your example by two lines:

```
{\everyeof={\noexpand}\xdef\filecontent{\csname @@input\endcsname outside_file }}%
\foreach \myitem in \filecontent
```

I suppose that the file doesn't include the TeX sensitive material (macros, TeX special characters like `%` etc.) and whole file contents can be processed by `\edef`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSV processing package for reading the lines of the input file. The following solution uses `csvsimple` but I guess you can get similar solutions with `datatool` and `pgfplotstable` also:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{outside_file.txt}
this,
is,
the content, of, a
file
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand\dosomethingwith[1]{\textbf{#1}\par}

\begin{document}

Read from file:\par
\csvloop{
  file=outside_file.txt,
  no head,
  check column count=false,
  command=\dosomethingwith\csvline,
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the output of `cat` to a macro:

[image]

### Notes:

- The macro `\SetMacroToShellOutput` is adapted from [Specify file name shell access via \@@input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102365/specify-file-name-shell-access-via-input)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{OutsideFile.tex}
this,
is,
the content, of, a
file
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\dosomethingwith[1]{\textbf{#1}\par}

\makeatletter
%% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102365/specify-file-name-shell-access-via-input
\newcommand\SetMacroToShellOutput[2]{%    
  \begingroup\endlinechar=\m@ne\everyeof{\noexpand}%
  \edef\TempResult{\endgroup
    \expandafter\def\noexpand#1{%
      \@@input|"#2" }}%
  \TempResult}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Output as expected:\par
\foreach \myitem in {this,is,the content, of, a file}
{\dosomethingwith\myitem}

\SetMacroToShellOutput{\MyFileContent}{cat OutsideFile.tex}
Output also as expected:\par
\foreach \myitem in \MyFileContent
{\dosomethingwith{\myitem}}

\end{document}
```