# How to run a program inside LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex

Is it possible to run a simple script inside LuaLaTeX or LaTeX?

For example, I need to use the calculator from the terminal. I'd like to write

> $echo "100.83*4.53" | bc

and obtain the result in LuaLaTeX or LaTeX. Is there a command (called `\runscript`, for instance) that runs a script from within LuaLaTeX or LaTeX and that I could use as follows:

> \runscript{echo "100.83*4.53" | bc}

and get "456.7599" as result?

Is it possible, perhaps with some Perl or Python script?

Comment: You can directly do the computation with Lua.

Comment: @dıʞsdoʇ What about `os.exec` in LuaTeX? Is it practical?

Comment: @egreg `os.exec()` is perfect for that task

Comment: @egreg meybe not. os.exec not include data to lualatex

Comment: I have to take back that `os.exec()` is perfect for the task. As @michal.h21 points out, `io.popen()` gets the input.

Comment: `LaTeX` solution is explained [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16790/write18-capturing-shell-script-output-as-command-variable/16794#16794).

Answer (score 12):

With LuaTeX you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

\def\foo{\directlua{dofile("runfunc.lua")}}
\foo
\end{document}
```

and the file `runfunc.lua` is this:

```
local i,j = io.popen([[echo "100.83*4.53" | bc]])
if not i then
  print(j)
  os.exit(-1)
end
tex.sprint(-2,string.gsub(i:read("*all"),"%s*$",""))
i:close()
```

run with

```
lualatex --shell-escape ‹filename.tex›
```

to allow `io.popen()`.

Comment: @Pankracy If it works for you, it would be nice to "accept" my answer by clicking on the checkmark right below the number of votes of that question.

Comment: @topskip This is brilliant, but is there a way to pass in `echo "100.83*4.53" | bc` as an argument to the `\foo` command from the LuaTeX document directly?

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676113/lua-os-execute-return-value and basically did this: `\newcommand\foo[1]{\directlua{
 local handle = io.popen([[#1]])
 local result = handle:read("*a")
 tex.print(result)
 handle:close()
}}` and then just `\foo{some shell command}`. I'm sure there will be quoting problems for anything involving special characters, but for now it works well enough.