# quickly changing all the file paths in a .tex file

Tags: paths, winedt

I use a `.tex` file that I sync with Dropbox across two computers, - mac (running win 7) and a pc.

The problem is that the `.tex` file is large, and contains a lot of tex commands (even user-written ones) like:

`\addbibresource{D:/Gdrive/Drop/Dropbox/latex/main/my.file.tex}`

Of course, this is the absolute path on my PC and the same file on my mac looks like:

`\addbibresource{C:\Dropbox\latex\main\my.file.tex}`

Note how `/` are changed in `\` and how the path is different.

My question is: how can I simply (and quickly) change all the paths when I move from my pc to my mac and vice versa? I use the latest winedt version to edit my latex file.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You **must not** use absolute paths. Use always relative paths. It is more simple and it is necessary for security reason too.

Comment: yes, I guess it is better. How can I used them? Are the relative paths relative to the position of the current .tex file? I that case I should write something like ``\addbibresource{...\main\other\my_other_file.tex}`` if I need to access a tex file that is located in the main\other folder? (Recall that the current tex file is located in main)

Comment: `\addbibresource{file.bib}` (sorry, but I think that `.bib` is more appropriate for `\addbibresource` command) is the solution if `latex/main/` is the working directory for both system.

Comment: If you need to access a `.tex` file that is located in the `main\other` folder you have to write `\input{main/other/file.tex}`

Comment: absolutely. indeeed a bibfile is more appropriate for addbibresource ! :) I have 2 last questions. Is there a command to define as a working directory the path of the current text file (maybe this is the default behavior). If I want to move up in the folder structure (folders that include the main repertoire), then I use the ``...`` command right?

Comment: First: I don't know. Second: `../` go back in the folder.

Comment: The paths are relative to the directory in which you are running `pdflatex` (or whichever). So if you run `pdflatex main/my.file` then the paths should be relative to the `latex` directory (i.e. to get to `main/other/file` you would simply put that). If you change into the `main` folder and run `pdflatex my.file`, then to get to the `other` folder you should put `../other/file`. This messed me up so many times when I was using subfiles... :-)

Comment: Are tools like `sed`, `awk`, and `tr` unavailable to you? I agree that you should always use relative paths, but for this one-time fix you might be able to do some good old regex-based substitution.

Comment: I dont know these tools, sorry. What can i do with them? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use a system dependent preamble for this kind of information.

On the mac:

```
% systempreamble.tex 
\newcommand{\pathtostuff}{D:/Gdrive/Drop/Dropbox/latex/main}
```

On the pc:

```
% systempreamble.tex

% latex uses / for paths, even on a pc
\newcommand{\pathtostuff}{C:/Dropbox/latex/main}
```

In your document

```
\input{systempreamble}
% ...
\addbibresource{\pathtostuff/my.file.tex}
```

(I haven't tested this since there's no easy MWE.)
You should also consider the comments about absolute path names.

Comment: This is smart, thanks. But an even smarter way to go would be to run a shell like command pwd in latex to get the current working directory. Is that possible?

Comment: I wouldn't use that strategy. If you want to try, the answer here may help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16790/write18-capturing-shell-script-output-as-command-variable

Comment: Thanks! May i ask you why you would not use that? The idea is just to run your tex file on whatever computer you want without messing manually with the code

Comment: Using a shell script escape is more complex, so harder to write and more prone to error. It may solve this particular problem, but it's less flexible. It might be worth doing if you were writing TeX for many users to compile on many computers. In this case I'd go with the generally useful design principle that puts macros in a preamble. You will do that often as you move from Noobie status. Once you've written the (system dependent) preamble you don't have to "mess manually with the code" - you just run it.