# pdfLaTeX not accepting shell commands despite shell-escape option

Tags: miktex, windows, input, shell-escape

I am testing the shell escape option, but I am stuck on a very early level -trying to do: `\input{|"time /t"}}`.
My pdfLaTeX is complaining:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `|"time /t".tex' not found.
```

As far as I know ([from other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16794/95312)):

> When shell escape is active and the primitive `\input` finds a `|`, it accepts as input the standard output of the following shell command.

I do not understand why `\input` is interpreting the command as file name in my case, as it is prepended with `|`.

My test code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\title{Shell escape test}
\author{MaciekS}

\begin{document}

Current time: \input{|"time /t"}

\end{document}
```

I tried running the code with both `--shell-escape` and `--enable-write18`.

Using pdfLaTeX version: MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6354 (1.40.18)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With miktex you need the options `--enable-pipes --shell-escape` for this.

Comment: That's the option I needed. Thanks! For some reason on other PC with MikTeX installed this worked with just `--shell-escape`.