# Accessing sqlite3 with xparse (under XeLaTeX)

Tags: xetex, xparse, shell-escape, sql

I was very happy when I read [egreg's 2019 Addendum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16790/write18-capturing-shell-script-output-as-command-variable) about how to launch a shell script from LaTeX and grab the output.

But when I tried to use it to connect with a SQLite database, I got a LaTeX3 error. Here is the (minimal) code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\captureshell}{som}
 {
  \sdaau_captureshell:Ne \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl { #3 }
  \IfBooleanT { #1 }
   {% we may need to stringify the result
    \tl_set:Nx \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl
     { \tl_to_str:N \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl }
   }
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_set_eq:NN #2 \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__sdaau_captureshell_out_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sdaau_captureshell:Nn
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { #2 } { } #1
  \tl_trim_spaces:N #1 % remove leading and trailing spaces
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sdaau_captureshell:Nn { Ne }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\captureshell{sqlite3 /hom/yannis/texmf/yannis.db 'select title from title where id="grafematik2020/hara/hara.tex"'}

\end{document}
```

The error says I'm not allowed to use double-quotes in shell commands:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Quotes in shell command 'sqlite3 /hom/yannis/texmf/yannis.db
(LaTeX3)        'select title from title where
(LaTeX3)        id="grafematik2020/hara/hara.tex"''.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.34 ... where id="grafematik2020/hara/hara.tex"'}
                                                  
? H

Shell commands cannot contain quotes (").
```

How can I nest a string inside an SQL command inside a shell command line, without using double-quotes?

Writing the value of the `id` argument without quotes is against SQL syntax: it considers it as a column name…

[PS. No, I do not wish to use LuaTeX or Context, even though I know that they are better suited for talking with sqlite3.]

Comment: That will be hard (if not impossible) because the web2c implementation of `\input` drops quotes when scanning a file name (even if you use the syntax with braces available since last year), so when you do the command `\input{|ls "/some/path/with spaces"}` it will execute the shell command `ls /some/path/with spaces`.  `expl3` just warns you that your command won't work as intended due to the engine limitation.  I'm afraid you'll have to find your way around without the quotes

Comment: Last year Karl and I tried to find a way to preserve quotes with the (plain) syntax `\input{...}`, but that would be inconsistent with other primitives like `\pdffilesize`, that take a braced file name and also drops quotes.  Basically we're stuck with no quotes in `\input` :(

Comment: Are double quotes " the only character I cannot use? At worst I can go through a filter that will systematically replace some other character (for example ＂, the full-width version of the double quote) into double quotes.

Comment: if sqlite accepts single quotes you could use `\'` to get a single quote in to a '-delimted string at the shell level,but a generic way to avoid all quoting issues is to use `\immediate\write` to write the entire command line  to `tmp.sh` then use write 18 to execute  `bash ./tmp.sh`

Comment: @yannis As far as I recall, yes, only `"` (ASCII 34).  Knuth's original implementation stopped scanning a file name at a space character, so the quote syntax was introduced to allow `\input "/some/file/with spaces"`, and the implementation recklessly kills all `"` in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have (directly) have double quotes `"` (ASCII 34) in shell commands for the same reason you can't have them in file names in web2c TeX implementations (TeX Live, MiKTeX, etc.).

---

Shell-escaping is implemented as a pseudo-file, so you use I/O primitives (`\openin`, `\write`, `\input`) to interact with the shell, thus all restrictions for file names apply for shell commands.

---

Knuth's original TeX implementation did not allow spaces in file names (for the greater good :) because it used a blank space as the terminator of a file name.  You can still see that implementation if you use the primitive `\input` (in LaTeX it is `\@@input`) syntax:

```tex
\input my_file.tex text after
```

the line above will input `my_file.tex`, do whatever is in there, then typeset `text after`.

To allow spaces in file names, in 2004 Olaf W implemented quoted file names as a filesystem-dependent change in TeX (thus affecting Knuth TeX), so you can type:

```tex
\input "file with spaces.tex" text after
```

but the implementation also allows you to type

```tex
\input file" "with" "spaces.tex text after
```

and it will remove *all* quotes in the process, while preserving spaces found after an odd number of quotes.

The issue with that implementation is that quotes are removed from a file name, no matter what (even with braced filename syntax), so it is currently not possible to use quotes anywhere in a file name (thus not anywhere in a shell command:  `expl3` only stops you from using that command because it will likely not work as you expect without the quotes).

---

That said, that limitation is for file names handled from within TeX.  David's suggestion should work fine because quotes don't go through TeX's file name parsing:

```tex
\newwrite\tmp
\openout\tmp{tmp.sh}
\immediate\write\tmp{ls "/some/path/with spaces/"}
\closeout\tmp

\input{|bash tmp.sh} % \input{"|bash tmp.sh"} if in LaTeX, or your own \captureshell command
```